# How can I write a swap function in scheme?

Tags: scheme, swap

I have a homework where I have to write a function that will take two variables/numbers and swaps them, then displays the result after swapping (in Scheme), I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution.

Can anyone please help ?

Example:

`(swap a b)`

Output:

`b a`

I found a code someone wrote, it's a function that takes a list as a parameter, then makes another list and place the contents of the first list in the second one but swapped.

`(define (swap lst)`

`(cond ((or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)))`

```
     lst)
  
    (else
   
     (cons (cadr lst)
  
           (cons (car lst)
                         (swap (cddr lst))))))
```

I didn't get any errors in this, but I tried to print the list and it didn't get swapped.

Comment: Can you post the wording of the question, or an example of (swap a b) showing what a and b refer to?

Comment: If it's supposed to actually swap the values of two variables, you need to use macros. It is very unlikely that you have learned about macros yet. It's much more likely that you have misunderstood the exercise.

Comment: That code does produce a pairwise swapped list (see [here](https://ideone.com/iHfmJB)). You probably expected it to modify the list you passed as an argument, but that's not how any of this works.

Comment: BTW: there are [excellent](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) [books](https://htdp.org/) available for free online.

Comment: Also free online is [The Scheme Programming Language](https://scheme.com/tspl4/) by R. Kent Dybvig; this can serve as a reference for R6RS Scheme, but also has a [Getting Started](https://scheme.com/tspl4/start.html) chapter which may be more accessible than works focussing on computation/software design.

Comment: tbh we never learned the language it's just an impossible question made by my professor, thanks to all of you who commented.. as for what i've searched and tried to learn there's not really a simple way.

Comment: You never learned the language, but you have homework in it? That's very odd. I see two possibilities (other than a really weird professor): you have either misunderstood the problem, or you are expected to conclude that it is an impossible task.

Comment: Odd right? You see the problem here is actually my weird prof, she was actually "supposed" to help us learn the language, the project had parts where first i do things in Pascal (which i didn't learn as well), then scheme, then there would be a third language. I am sure i understand the task, and maybe you are right in stating that it is an impossible task. The professor is well known for this and many problems in my uni.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth if you want to swap two variables in Scheme what you need is a *macro*:

```
(define-syntax swap!
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ a b)
     (let ((tmp a))
       (set! a b)
       (set! b tmp)))))
```

And now:

```
> (define a 1)
> (define b 2)
> (swap! a b)
> a
2
> b
1
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted, no Scheme *function* called as `(swap a b)` can "interchange" a and b. It's trivial,
of course, to output the arguments in that order:

```
(define a "first")
(define b "second ")
(define (swap a b)
  (display b)
  (display a))
  
;(swap a b) displays: second first
```

Using `set!`, as one might do in some languages, doesn't work:

```
(define a "first")
(define b "second ")
(define (swap a* b*)
  (let ((tmp a*))
    (set! a* b*)
    (set! b* tmp)
    (display a*)
    (display b*)))

(for-each display `("before swap: a = " ,a " b = " ,b "\n(swap a b) displays: "))
(swap a b)
(for-each display `("\nafter swap: a = " ,a " b = " ,b))
```

Displays:

```
before swap: a = first b = second 
(swap a b) displays: second first
after swap: a = first b = second 
>
```

Comment: (The discoverers of Scheme, [revisiting its origin](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227202780_The_First_Report_on_Scheme_Revisited)
report that they "...settled on call-by-value as the “official”
evaluation order for Scheme only after a fair amount of deliberation and debate.")